# Fishers method and multiple hypothesis testing

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have measurements the protein level of ~1000 proteins in 10 biological tissues, and have thus performed 10.000 t-tests.

I am now doing a meta analysis, and thus using Fishers method to combine the 10x1000 P-values, into 1000 P-values.

Obviously I need to correct for multiple hypothesis comparison... but how:

1. you have performed 10.000 t-tests, thus you had 10.000 hypothesis.
2. you have used Fishers methods 1000 times, thus you had 1000 hypothesis.

I feel like 2) is the correct answer, but I am less than 95% sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with Bonferroni correction.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction

Holm method can also be used.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method

UDP. Your final answer depends on combined Fisher's test, you have to use multiple hypothesis testing correction for 1000 Fisher's tests.
The fact that each Fisher's tests "consists" of 10 test is taken into account by Fisher's test itself.

Comment: I know... but should I multiply by 1.000 or 10.000 if I use Bonferroni?

Comment: If your final answer depends on combined Fisher's test (looks like it is), you have to use Bonferroni for 1000.

Comment: if you are sure, and you change your answer to be what you wrote in your comment, then I will up vote, and accept in a few hours.